# What's wrong with my sql in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

What's wrong with my sql in oracle? There are some data in my table,I select all of them and I can get them.but I can not search them if I add a condition.When did I add  single or double quotation marks in my sql?Now I find that when I write some search statement,I must add   single quotation marks.And when I write some insert statement,I must add  double quotation marks.Or my sql will run bad.How to judge when should I use the different quotation in my sql?

```
select * from  T_STUDENT
```

and the result is:

```
 sex(varchar2)  phone(varchar2) birthtime(timestamp)
 1 13553812147 2016-06-03 16:02:00.799 **
```

When I add a search condition,but the result is null.

```
 //error:ORA-000904
select * from T_STUDENT where phone='13553812147' 
//error:ORA-000904
select * from T_STUDENT where PHONE='13553812147' 
//run well but result is null
select * from T_STUDENT where 'phone'='13553812147'
```

And the same question I meet in the insert statement.

```
//error:ORA-000904
insert into T_STUDENT (sex,phone,birthtime) values('1','12345645454','2016-06-04 16:02:00.799')
//error:ORA-000928 missing select keyword
insert into T_STUDENT ('sex','phone','birthtime')  values('1','12345645454','2016-06-04 16:02:00.799')
//run well but must add double quotation marks
insert into T_STUDENT ("sex","phone","birthtime")  values('1','12345645454','2016-06-04 16:02:00.799')
```

Comment: For those who don't know all ORA codes by heart: **ORA-00904: invalid identifier**

Comment: better use table alias and let your editor suggest the column name

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález,I know the meaning,but wonder why.

Comment: I figured out. But there's no need to make questions harder to answer than they should. After all you're who's more interested in getting an answer ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your table was defined using double quotes around the column names:

```
create table t_student
 ( "sex" varchar2(1)
 , "phone" varchar2(30)
 , "birthtime" timestamp
 );
```

Using double quotes makes the names case-sensitive and so for ever after they must be referenced in double quotes, since by default Oracle is nicely case-**insensitive**.  For this reason you should never use double quotes when creating tables, views etc.

Comment: If it is case-insensitive,Why do I use both capital or  lowercase column in a search statement it still can not get the search result.

Comment: Do you get "invalid identifier" instead of "unknown column"? That was my first suspect but don't have an Oracle box here to test.

Comment: I get "invalid identifier" .And only when I add single quotation marks I can run well but still  get the NULL searching result.

Comment: I design them in a graphic interface using navicat.And now I find the sql:CREATE TABLE "NewTable" (
"phone" VARCHAR2(255) NULL ,
"sex" VARCHAR2(255) NULL 
)
NOCOMPRESS
;

Comment: @flowerit single quotation defines a string literal. When you do 'phone'='13553812147' you compare two inequal strings and you get no result

Comment: It is case-insensitive like what you say .But the seaching result is really  not  what I want.It return NULL.But in fact it has one record.

Comment: @flower double quotation defines exact identifier name and is case sensitive. do WHERE "phone"='13553812147' if your table definition shows cols in quotes

Comment: @micklesh,I get your meaning.Thank you.But if I do not use single quotation,it can not run if it is case-insensitive.

Comment: see the docs please https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements008.htm

Answer (score 1):

I've had the chance to look at this and Tony Andrews' answer is correct, you actually get *invalid identifier* as error message when you type an invalid column, which includes a case mismatch, though the **error message will mention the exact identifier**:

```
SQL> select * from T_STUDENT where phone='13553812147';
select * from T_STUDENT where phone='13553812147'
                              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "PHONE": invalid identifier


SQL> select * from T_STUDENT where funny_bunny='13553812147';
select * from T_STUDENT where funny_bunny='13553812147'
                              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "FUNNY_BUNNY": invalid identifier
```

The only thing missing from his answer is that Oracle will always make an internal cast to uppercase for any unquoted identifier, as the full error message illustrates. That's why `phone='13553812147'` won't match a column defined as `"phone"` (but `"phone"='13553812147'` will do).

Last but not least, single quotes define plain strings rather than object names so when you do this:

```
select * from T_STUDENT where 'phone'='13553812147'
```

... you aren't filtering by `phone` column at all. Instead, you have a constant condition that's always false (text "phone" equals text "13553812147").